# Resultset with pivot table as sub query - MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, pivot-table

I have two tables with following structure.
[image]

and

[image]

and I want results like this from one query.

CUSTOMER_CODE | CUSTOMER_NAME | LINE 1 |LINE 2 | LINE 3

we have to make first table as pivot, but how not sure.
Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything ?. You can post the query even if it is wrong

Comment: How are the lines connected to the second result set? Just a random order?

Comment: actually I'm getting how to start. I'm not good in database, but I just got a clue that we need convert first table as pivot so that its row can be converted in columns. Rest I'm not sure how.

Comment: What are your desired results?  Why does the second table repeat the same rows over and over?  Why does the output have `Line 1` twice?  Your question is not clear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just updated the 2nd table. The rows are not repeating, it was result of some random query. I have changed the image.

Comment: @JamesZ the PK or second table is being used as FK in first table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dynamic conditional aggregation   There were no table names, so TABLE1 relates to Image1

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max)=''
Select @SQL = @SQL+',[Line '+cast([Line#] as varchar(25))+']=max(case when [Line#]='+cast([Line#] as varchar(25))+' then EMail else '''' end)'
 From (Select Distinct [Line#] from Table1) A
 Order By [Line#] 

Select @SQL='
Select A.Customer_Code
      ,B.Customer_Branch_Name'+@SQL+' 
 From  Table1 A 
 Join  Table2 B 
   on  A.Customer_Code=B.Customer_Branch 
 Group By A.Customer_Code,B.Customer_Branch_Name'
Exec(@SQL)
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: Thanks John. Your query looks promising as it returns the exact data which I need. Actually I need to run this query using Link Sever. I edited it as per my server and table name but getting a syntax error. Please find my query at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37107813/query.txt as I can't past my query here due to comment box length limitation.

Comment: @Ans you may have to wrap the entire sql in one openquery()  or a stored procedure on the linked server  check http://blog.falafel.com/t-sql-creating-dynamic-pass-through-queries-for-use-with-openquery/